# Passing vars to awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, ksh

I have huge file that needs to be split into multiple files.

I'm using `split`, which is working fine

```
file=home/sap/dim/deltafile.D2017313.T100058932IDL.gz

gunzip -c ${file} | split -l 10000000 -d -a 4 - ${file%/*}/"working".$v_procid.`basename ${file%.*}`.part.
```

With `awk` it is also working. But when I pass the variable `awk` through, it is failing.

```
gunzip -c ${file} | awk 'NR%10000000==1 {x="F" ++i} {print > x}'
```

`awk` creates files named `F1`, `F2`...

I need this using variables, and have tried all different examples. No luck.

Comment: What exactly does fail, and how? What do you need the variables for?

Comment: similarly how i defined in split ${file%/*}/"working".$v_procid.`basename ${file%.*}`.part.

Comment: So you want to pass `$v_procid` to `awk` to built the filename?

Comment: I need to pass filepath and filename as a variable in awk . similar to what i did in split cmd.

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass data to `awk` with `-v var=value`, any number of -v options may be present:

```
awk -v foo=FOO 'END {print foo}' </dev/null
awk -v foo=FOO -v bar=BAR 'END {print foo, bar}' </dev/null
```

As usual you can also use shell variables etc as part of the assignment:

```
awk -v bar="$PWD" 'END {print bar}' </dev/null

file=home/sap/dim/deltafile.D2017313.T100058932IDL.gz
awk -v bar="${file%/*}" 'END {print bar}' </dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

Construct the static part of the filename outside of `awk` and pass it to an `awk` variable:

```
prefix="${file%/*}/working.$v_procid.$(basename ${file%.*}).part"

gunzip -c "$file" |
awk -v p="$prefix" 'NR % 10000000 == 1 { f = p "" ++i } { print >f }'
```

The `f = p "" ++i` bit could be replaced by `f = sprintf("%s%s", p, ++i)`.

If you expect to generate a large number of output files, you may want to explicitly `close()` the previous file before writing to the next output file, so that you don't accidently run out of available file descriptors:

```
awk -v p="$prefix" 'NR % 10000000 == 1 { if (f) close(f); f = p "" ++i } { print >f }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another point to add to the previous two answers. There is a second way of passing variables, by adding them to the command line after the program has been specified.

```
awk program.awk /path/to/input var=value second/input
```

From the [GNU Awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Other-Arguments.html#Other-Arguments)

> The distinction between file name arguments and variable-assignment
>   arguments is made when awk is about to open the next input file. At
>   that point in execution, it checks the file name to see whether it is
>   really a variable assignment; if so, awk sets the variable instead of
>   reading a file.
>
> Therefore, the variables actually receive the given values after all
>   previously specified files have been read. In particular, the values
>   of variables assigned in this fashion are not available inside a BEGIN
>   rule (see BEGIN/END), because such rules are run before awk begins
>   scanning the argument list.

So while

```
awk -v var=value program.awk
```

allows you to pass values for the start of the program, before any BEGIN parts, you can also change the program variables as you go, if needs be.